# Need to return List of Custom Object using JPA @Query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpql

I've a custom object

```
@Component
public class SaleReport {

    private Date date;
    private String customerName;
    private String phoneNo;
    private String productName;
    private Integer quantity;
    private Double totalAmount;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Double getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(Double totalAmount) {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }
}
```

I need to return List of this object using a `JpaRepository<Sale, Integer>`
The `SaleRepository` is as follow:

```
@Repository
public interface SaleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sale, Integer> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT B.order_date AS date, E.customer_name AS customerName, " +
            "E.phone_no AS phoneNo, D.product_name AS productName, C.quantity AS quantity, " +
            "C.total_price AS totalAmount " +
            "FROM SALE A " +
            "INNER JOIN A.quotation_id B " +
            "INNER JOIN B.quotation_id C " +
            "INNER JOIN C.product_id D " +
            "INNER JOIN B.customer_id E " +
            "WHERE (B.order_date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date)", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<SaleReport> getSaleReportByDate(@Param("from_date")String fromDate, @Param("to_date")String toDate);

}
```

Here is my Controller method:

```
@GetMapping("api/report/sale/{from_date}/{to_date}")
        public List<SaleReport> getSaleReportByDate(@PathVariable("from_date") String fromDate, @PathVariable("to_date") String toDate){
        return saleRepository.getSaleReportByDate(fromDate, toDate);
}
```

While I run the code it shows this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'a'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
```

My DATABASE NAME is alright. It works perfectly while I request in other methods.
Please suggest me an ideal solution.

Comment: This exception is because of application could not found database name.Ensure that you have database named 'a' by checking manually.

Comment: Why the query is searching for database named 'a' ..?here is my database informations `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3366/andropos_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1525`

Comment: FROM SALE A " +
            "INNER JOIN A.quotation_id B " + see this. you are trying to do something with 'a' database only

Comment: I've changed the `SALE A` to Only `SALE`. in that case the query is searching for database named 'sale'. Now what?

Comment: SaleReport annotated with "Component". I think it should be annotated with "Entity" ?

Comment: @Habil this is not an entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring has an annotation called `@SqlResultSetMapping`
This annotation can be used for above problem. Details about this annotation can be found from following link:

[Annotation Type ConstructorResult](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html)

This is actually mapping a hibernate query result into a plain `POJO` Class. Thats what actually needed.

```
Example:

   Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
      "SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(o) as orderCount, AVG(o.price) AS avgOrder " +
      "FROM Customer c, Orders o " +
      "WHERE o.cid = c.id " +
      "GROUP BY c.id, c.name",
      "CustomerDetailsResult");

   @SqlResultSetMapping(
       name="CustomerDetailsResult",
       classes={
          @ConstructorResult(
               targetClass=com.acme.CustomerDetails.class,
                 columns={
                    @ColumnResult(name="id"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="name"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="orderCount"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="avgOrder", type=Double.class)
                    }
          )
       }
      )
```

Put `@SqlResultSetMapping` into top of any `@Entity` and make sure the `datatype` returning from database is same as your `POJO` Class `datatype`.

Hope this will help you. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You need to create a constructor for the `SaleReport` class that accepts all the parameters that you use in the `select` statement and in the exact order.

**2)** Alter your query so that you wrap the selected columns with a `new` statement:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new org.mypackage.SaleReport(B.order_date AS date,"
                        + "E.customer_name AS customerName, "
                        + "E.phone_no AS phoneNo, D.product_name AS productName, 
                        + "C.quantity AS quantity, " +
                        + "C.total_price AS totalAmount) " +
            "FROM SALE A " +
            "INNER JOIN A.quotation B " +
            "INNER JOIN B.quotation C " +
            "INNER JOIN C.product D " +
            "INNER JOIN B.customer E " +
            "WHERE (B.order_date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date)")
```

**3)** In my opinion you don't need a native query here and you can use HQL directly (changed joins).

Comment: Shows following error:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'saleController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'saleRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'saleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List me.chonchol.androposweb.repository.SaleRepository.getSaleReportByDate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!`

Comment: Make sure you use the entity instance variable names instead of direct db column names

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer might help you !!

**Sale** is your entity class and **SaleReport is pojo** class.

```
public List<SaleReport> getSaleReportByDate(@Param("from_date")String fromDate, @Param("to_date")String toDate);
```

you can not return a pojo class list from database.It return entity class list.
Use public List  not   public List

```
public List<Sale> getSaleReportByDate(@Param("from_date")String fromDate, @Param("to_date")String toDate);

@Repository
public interface SaleRepository extends JpaRepository<**Sale**, Integer>
```

you have to map Entity Class list to POJO class list.

**Mapping of Entity class list to a pojo class list:**
As there are lot of ways to achieve this still
Easiest solution is loop over entity class and set entity attribute to pojo attribute:

I don't suggest to use constructor because some times you may want to set only several fields not all fields of POJO class.

```
Arraylist<SaleReport> sr = new Arraylist<SaleReport>();
ArrayList<Sale> saleEntityList= saleRepository.getSaleReportByDate(fromDate,toDate);
for(Sale  s : saleEntityList){
    saleReport = new SaleReport();
    saleReport.setDate(s.getDate);
    //same for all attributes
    sr.add(saleReport);
} 
return sr;
```

Here sr is your POJO list.